# Facebook Single sign-on integration to my application - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have implemented the `Facebook`'s `Single sign-on (SSO)` to my application. I followed the [example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) given by `facebook` and all the code was taken from it.

It works perfectly. But my problem now is that i need to know if the login was successful or failed. I need to store this result (if success/fail) in my application as `NSUserDefault`. `Facebook` doesn't return a `JSON` string saying if the login was a success or failed.

So can someone please tell me how do i know if the login was a success or failure.

Please point me to a tutorial or post some code so that i could understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fbDidLogin gets fired, then login was successful so you can put code or change variable in here.

Answer (score 2):

you have a delegate function in the FBSessionDelegate tell you that user login successfully .. the function name fbDidLogin .. inside it you store the token access and expiry date .. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In the -(void)fbDidLogin delegate method add this code

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Yes this is already added to my code. So what you say is, if the `FBAccessTokenKey` and  `FBExpirationDateKey` is not nil then we have had a valid sign-in ? And, if i have to logout, then should i have to make `FBAccessTokenKey` and  `FBExpirationDateKey` NIL ?